# Angular 2: User drag for touch devices at runtime

Tags: css, angular, styles, touch, drag

I have a grid that allows items inside to be dragged and resized. I want the drag effect to appear when an item is dragged. If I dd user-drag attribute in css against the element, it doesn't allow for resize. So, I am attaching that css property to the element at runtime (using Renderer.setElementStyle) on MouseMove method. It is all working perfectly for mouse related operations.

Now, I need to replicate the same for touch devices. Basically, I need to attach the user-drag property to an element on touchStart event. Using Renderer.setElementStyle does not help.

Questions:
1. Is drag effect visible on touch devices if we use user-drag property?
2. If yes, how we set this at runtime in an Angular application?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this one:

HTML5 drag and drop API does not support touch based interactions. Only mouse. So setting this attribute won't matter for touch cases.

To achieve drag and drop one should either build that using touch events (touchstart, touchmove, touchend, touchcancel) or leverage libraries.